# Problema con variables AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, funciones

tengo el siguiente problema tengo una variable definida en mi documento php de inicio la cual es la siguiente

```
<?php
  $var = $_GET['pagina'];
?>

<script>
  var variable = <?php echo $var ?>
</script>
```

en mi consulta ajax la tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
$(obtener_registros());

function obtener_registros(clientes){

  $.ajax({
    url : 'consulta2.php',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'html',
    data :  {clientes: clientes},
  })

  .done(function(resultado){
    $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
  });
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
  var valorBusqueda=$('#search').val();
  if (valorBusqueda!=""){
    obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
  }
  else{
    obtener_registros();
  }
});
```

y en mi documento php `consulta2.php` llamo la variable de esta manera

```
echo $_POST['variable'];
```

mi consulta funciona perfectamente el detalle esta cuando agrego la variable a la consulta ajax de la siguiente manera:

```
data : {clientes: clientes, variable: variable},
```

al hacerlo de esta manera mi consulta ya no se ejecuta a menos que indique un botón que al darle click ejecute la función obtener_registros() pero esto obviamente me inhabilita la funcion de buscar que tengo definida en mi consulta ajax.

me podrían ayudar un poco y ver por que al incluir la variable, mi función no se ejecuta automáticamente como lo hace sin la variable.

Comment: En dónde tenés el script de javascript? Está después de declarar la variable? Está en otro archivo después de declarar la variable? Probaste haciendo un `console.log(variable);`? Qué quisiste hacer con esta línea `$(obtener_registros());`?

Comment: son 3 archivos uno es mi archivo donde coloca la consulta que contiene solo una variable php que es la que obtiene el $_GET y donde se declara la variable de java, el segundo archivo es donde viene la consulta ajax y el 3er archivo es el de cosnsulta2.php. el codigo `$(obtener_registros());` lo utilizo para llamar la funcion y que se ejecute al abrir el primer documento, todo funciona correctamente, lo unico que quiero resolver es por que al añadir la variable del primer archivo en la cosnsulta ajax ya no se me ejecuta mi script de manera automatica como lo hace regularmente.

Comment: Hola @AlexisGarcia que tal?? no me queda muy claro el código,ni por qué al principio del codigo pasas un parámetro y luego agregas dos,eso no lo estoy entendiendo muy bien,ya que donde recoges el valor del parámetro `variable`.Además, al controlar que este vacío el valor de ´$('#search')´ haces la consulta de todas maneras.

Comment: ok me explico, el primer parametro `$(obtener_registros());` ejecuta la fucnion que esta debajo: `function obtener_registros(clientes){` y esta misma funcion me ejecuta la consulta la cual me muestra todos los resultados de la BD y el tercer parámetro me ejecuta la función según las letras que yo introduzco. todo funciona bien. solo el hecho de migrar la variable que comento en mi pregunta no me ejecuta la funcion de manera automatica como se supone que lo haga y en su lugar tengo que optar por poner un booton que llame la funcion pero de esta manera no me sirve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te lo publico como respuesta pero te pregunté sobre el orden porque esto difiere en la ejecución de javascript.

> **Aclaración**: *java* no es la abreviación de *javascript*, decir eso es decir que estás hablando de otro lenguaje de programación totalmente diferente.

Volviendo al error, noté varios detalles por el cuál puede que esté funcionando mal, uno de ellos es la siguiente línea:  `$(obtener_registros());`.
Por lo que veo, intentaste ejecutar la función de esa forma, pero esa encapsulación es errónea. La forma ideal de encapsular el código son de las siguientes maneras:

**En jquery:**

```
// esto quiere decir que todo lo que se encuentra por dentro de esto
// se va a ejecutar una vez que esté resuelto el DOM, es decir una vez
// que termine de cargar el HTML
$(document).ready(function() { ... });

// forma abreviada, fue la que utilizaste
$(function() { ... });
```

**En javascript puro:**

```
// tiene la misma finalidad que la anterior
(function() { ... })();
```

> ¿En qué afecta todo esto?
>    Es que al ejecutar la página va a considerar el orden de los archivos y de las variables, si la variable la declarás después del archivo donde tenés el ajax, entonces cuando quieras llamarlo te va a devolver que la variable `variable` es `undefined` pero si agregas que llame a la variable por dentro del encapsulamiento, te va a devolver el valor de dicha variable.

---

### Solución:

- Alterar el orden de los archivos
- Encapsular las funciones

Suponiendo que son 3 archivos como mencionaste. En el `index.html`:

```
<!-- primero carga la variable global -->
<script type="text/javascript src="variable-global.js"></script>
<!-- luego puedo utilizar la variable global en el siguiente archivo -->
<script type="text/javascript src="funcion-ajax.js"></script>
```

**funcion-ajax.js**

```
// una vez que cargue el DOM
$(function() {

  function obtener_registros(clientes){

    $.ajax({
      url : 'consulta2.php',
      type : 'POST',
      dataType : 'html',
      data :  {clientes: clientes, variable: variable},
    })
    .done(function(resultado){
      $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
    });
  }

  $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
    var valorBusqueda=$('#search').val();
    if (valorBusqueda!=""){
      obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
    }
    else{
      obtener_registros();
    }
  });

  // ejecuto la función
  obtener_registros();

});
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias por la aclaración y explicarme un poco acerca de la estructuración del documento esto me sirvió de maravilla.